How to integrate the GMP library into a C++ cryptography library on windows?
For fun, and to learn, I'm making a cryptography library in C++ on Windows. For my first attempt I found a small C++ library called InfInt that I used to implement ECDSA. But once I finally got it working I found that it was quite slow. So I profiled my project and found the bottleneck was in the InfInts arithmetic (specifically division unsurprisingly) that I used in my extended Euclidean algorithm to find modular inverses.
So I am looking to improve its performance by using the GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library (GMP) instead of InfInt. However, I'm a bit overwhelmed by the size of the GMP library and unsure about the best approach for incorporating it into my project.
I found the GMP library online, and downloaded and attempted to bundle the library into my project by adding it to a "external/gmp" directory. But quickly found out that the library is quite sizable, and there are parts that I probably wont need. Looking into it I will probably only need the mpz class.
Specifically, I'm interested in:

Trimming down GMP to include only the necessary arithmetic operations for algorithms like ECC and RSA.
Integrating GMP into my project either using CMake's FetchContent/ ExternalProject_Add feature (if possible) or by bundleing/ embedding a trimmed version of GMP in my project.

I would prefer to do this to avoid other people having the same headache if they download the library, and have to also figure out how to link in GMP.
I would greatly appreciate any insights or best practices from anyone who has experience with GMP or similar libraries. How did you approach integrating GMP into your project? Are there any specific considerations I should keep in mind?
Note: I also attempted to use another library called ctbignum, but it also gave me a headache. So I figured if I am gonna get a headache either way might as well go with the headache which will give me the faster library haha.
